# Override submit event of child component

Tags: vue.js

I have 2 components, one for a 'create form' and an other for an 'edit form'.
 I am using the 'create-form' inside the 'edit-form'. Everything works well, except for my submit method.
I was hoping to override the submit event of the 'create-form', however it always gets called first.
Is it possible and the right way I am trying to do? Here is also a fiddle with what I am trying to achieve:
https://jsfiddle.net/DarkFruits/197wndq9/1/

HTML

```
<template id="form-create">
  <form @submit.self.prevent="raiseSubmit">
    <button type="submit">SUBMIT</button>
  </form>

</template>

<template id="form-edit">
  <form-create v-bind:user="myUser" @submit.stop.capture.prevent="raiseSubmit" ></form-create>
</template>

<div id="app">
  <form-edit></form-edit>  
</div>
```

JS

```
Vue.component('form-create', {
    template: '#form-create',
    props: {
    user: {
        default: {
        username: '',
        email: '',
      }
    }
  },

  methods: {
    raiseSubmit() {
        console.log("I do not want Create submit to be called");
    }
  }
})

Vue.component('form-edit', {
    template: '#form-edit',
    data() {
    return {
        myUser: {
        username: 'max',
        email: 'max@example.com'
      }
    }
  },

  methods: {
    raiseSubmit() {
        console.log("I want Edit submit to be called");
    }
  }
})

new Vue({
    el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {}
  }
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to override something in a component, you will need to code the component to allow the override. One way would be to add a Boolean prop that, if set, the component emits a submit event (effectively bubbling), but if not, it runs its usual handler.

```js
Vue.component('form-create', {
  template: '#form-create',
  props: {
    user: {
      default: {
        username: '',
        email: '',
      }
    },
    defer: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false
    }
  },
  methods: {
    raiseSubmit(e) {
      if (this.defer) {
        this.$emit('submit', e);
      } else {
        console.log("I do not want Create submit to be called");
      }
    }
  }
})

Vue.component('form-edit', {
  template: '#form-edit',
  data() {
    return {
      myUser: {
        username: 'max',
        email: 'max@example.com'
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    raiseSubmit() {
      console.log("I want Edit submit to be called");
    }
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {}
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.3.4/vue.min.js"></script>
<template id="form-create">
  <form @submit.prevent="raiseSubmit">
    {{user.username}}
    <button type="submit">SUBMIT</button>
  </form>
  
</template>

<template id="form-edit">
  <form-create v-bind:user="myUser" defer @submit.prevent="raiseSubmit"></form-create>
</template>

<div id="app">
  <form-edit></form-edit>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh yeah you're right. I should have known that I cannot listen to the events of my child component. >.<   
Thanks!